# How do I organize my api routes vs my page routes in a SPA?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, single-page-application

Let's say I have a resource `squids`.

There is a page in my app to add `squids` with a form describing their inkiness etc, I'd say this form should be at `localhost/squid`.

Then the post req to make a new squid goes to the same place `localhost/squid`.

But what about when I want to `GET` a list of all squids? How do you/should I structure and name these similar routes?

i.e.

```
 // app/routes/squid.js

 router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('squid'));

 router.post('/', (req, res) => {
     saveSquid();
     res.render('dashboard');
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a prefix to all of your api calls as following:

```
GET /api/squids // will get squids back
```

and then you can still use /squids to render the page.

you can also use express router module to make a different router for the api:

```
var app = express();
var apiRouter = express.Router();
apiRouter.get('/squids', function(req,res){});

var pubRouter = express.Router();
pubRouter.get('/squids', function(req, res){})
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
app.use('/', pubRouter);
```